# yum - unexpected dependency

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Platform: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

I'm trying to download a set of rpm files for an offline installation. I have one master RPM that lists a set of dependencies. using a command like this

```
yumdownloader --releasever=/ --installroot=/a/dummy/place --resolve --destdir=/my/target  MyPackage
```

I'm getting all the packages I expect **and** one extra.

```
MQSeriesRuntime.x86_64 0:9.1.0-0
```

In an attempt to find out where that extra is coming from I've cut my master spec file down to having **no dependencies**, there are no Require statements in it and yet the extraneous dependency still appears. I start with a machine where my package is not installed, I clean and install the package, and it installs with no extraneous rpms.

```
yum clean all
yum -y install MyPackage
```

Then I issue the download command

```
$ sudo yumdownloader --releasever=/ --installroot=$DUMMYREPO_DIR --resolve --destdir=$RPMREPO_DIR  MyPackage
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MyPackage.noarch 0:5.0.1-0.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: MyPackage-5.0.1-0.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: MyPackage-5.0.1-0.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MQSeriesRuntime.x86_64 0:9.1.0-0 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

My question is what can cause the appearance of this MQSeriesRuntime, and more importantly, how can I get rid of it!

Presumably there's a caching issue somewhere, or some RPM-related database is corrupt. But if so, how do I recover?

Comment: No way to know without having the exact package. Your "ghost" package might be an indirect dependency (needed by some dependency). What is the problem with that package, anyway?

Comment: There are *no* Require statements in the Spec file for the RPM, no dependencies at all. I am trying to produce a minimal download and this extra file is relatively large. Something somewhere is broken.

Comment: MQSeriesRuntime either Provides or Enhance something which will take it into the transaction.